# Install package using setup.py

Tags: python, import, setup.py

I want to create and install my own packages, so I can import functionality.py into script.py into otehr functions in the program. Following on from [these instructions](https://www.datasciencelearner.com/importerror-attempted-relative-import-parent-package/), I have:

### Project structure

```py
/SRC
   /package_one
        __init__.py
        script.py #Note: script.py imports from functionality.py 
   /package_two
        __init__.py
        functionality.py
setup.py
```

### script.py

```py
from package_two import functionality
functionality.execute()
```

### funcitonality.py

```py
def execute(): 
    print ("Running functinality")
```

### setup.py

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(name = 'pckage_two', packages = find_packages())
```

### The problem

However,  when i run:

```py
C:\Users\XXXX\XXXX\src> python setup.py install
```

from Terminal (in VS code with Anaconda)
I get the following error:

```
the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'c:\\users\\XXXX\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\pckage_two-0.0.0-py3.9.egg'
```

#### other infomation

I am using Anaconda and VSCode, I have ran the python setup.py both from VScode terminal and Anaconda terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation on that site is rather out of date and you should not (unless you know exactly what you're doing) be creating a `setup.py` at all, nor should you be running `python setup.py install` which has legacy behavior that is no longer supported.

For more up-to-date information on modern Python packaging the best place to look, as of writing, is:

https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/